# Problem with scraping make my trip flight data using cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I am scraping Make My Trip Flight data for a project but for some reason it doesn't work. I've tried many selectors but none of them worked. On the other hand I also tried scraping another site with the same logic, and it worked. Can someone point out where did I go wrong?

I am using cheerio and axios

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
```

Make My Trip:

```
axios.get('https://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?itinerary=BOM-DEL-14/11/2020&tripType=O&paxType=A-1_C-0_I-0&intl=false&cabinClass=E').then(urlRes => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(urlRes.data);
    $('.fli-list.one-way').each((i, el) => {
        const airway = $(el).find('.airways-name ').text();
        console.log(airway);
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The other site for which the code works:

```
axios.get('https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/').then(urlRes => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(urlRes.data);
    $('.tease.article').each((i, el) => {
        const link = $(el).find('a.overlay').attr('href');
        console.log(link);
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** you should parse

- `https://voyager.goibibo.com/api/v2/flights_search/find_node_by_name_v2/?search_query=DEL&limit=15&v=2`

instead of

- `https://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?itinerary=BOM-DEL-14/11/2020&tripType=O&paxType=A-1_C-0_I-0&intl=false&cabinClass=E`

---

**Explanation** (hope it is clear enough)

Cause you're trying to parse heavy web application using one plain GET request ... it is impossible in this way :)
The main difference between provided urls:

- the second web page (yes just a page not js app like makemytrip) 'https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/' respond to you with a complete content
- makemytrip respond to you only with a js script, which do the work - loads data and etc.

To parse such complicated web apps you should investigate (press f12 in browser -> web) all requests which are running in your browser on page load and repeat these requests in your script ... like in this case you could notice API endpoint which responds with all needed data.

Comment: Can you please link some example or tutorial so that I can understand in a better way? I couldn't find that particular script which you mentioned. Sorry for asking again!

Comment: For example if you are using Firefox go read their tutorials https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools you can find link to flights api using "Network Monitor" - it is a core tool (your investigation of how to parser any particular site should start here)

Answer (score 0):

I think cheerio works just fine, I will recommend go over the HTML again and find a new element, class or something else to search for.

When I went into the given url I did not find .fli-list.one-way in any combination.

Just try to find something more particular to filter on.

If you still need help I can try and scrape it by myself and send you some code

Comment: This combination of classes is present, I am sure on that. I guess what @madzohan mentioned can be the reason. Can you please take a look at the code again :)

Comment: You will have to use a different website for this task because all the flight data in rendered via JavaScript which makes it almost impossible to scrap easily.
When you find your website go to the source code or inspect the specific element and do the same function with some minor changes for it to work, Good luck!